# Akka default logging to console pattern

Tags: scala, logging, akka, logback

Very simple question: how can I modify the (very cluttered) default pattern for log messages in Akka (I'm using 2.2.3). I assume it's not using logback because adding a logback.xml file didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before you can use your logback.xml file, you must first tell Akka to use the logback logging backend. This can easily be done using the Akka configuration file, as [described in the Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/logging.html#SLF4J).

The pattern for the default logger is unfortunately hard coded ([see `trait StdOutLogger`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/event/Logging.scala?source=cc)):

```
private val date = new Date()
private val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")
private val errorFormat = "[ERROR] [%s] [%s] [%s] %s%s"
private val errorFormatWithoutCause = "[ERROR] [%s] [%s] [%s] %s"
private val warningFormat = "[WARN] [%s] [%s] [%s] %s"
private val infoFormat = "[INFO] [%s] [%s] [%s] %s"
private val debugFormat = "[DEBUG] [%s] [%s] [%s] %s"
```

Comment: Does it mean it's not possible to change the ConsoleLogger pattern at all with akka ?